# Convergence of sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n+1)x^n$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, sequences-and-series

How can I find to what this sum converges to?

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} n(n+1)x^n$$

I proved that it converges when

$$|x| < 1$$

but no idea how to find what it sums to.

Comment: Hint: differentiate $\sum x^{n+1}$ twice, and then multiply by $x$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the ratio test? @David: A bit more than Guy was asking for.

Comment: He actually said he wanted to compute the value of the series.

Comment: I used different tests to prove it converges. I need to find the sum it converges to. I'm not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: Just follow David hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the sum of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n*(n+1)*x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909880/find-the-sum-of-the-power-series-sum-n-1-infty-nn1xn)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=x^1+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$
Then, for $|x|<1$
$$
f'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots
$$
$$\eqalign{
f''(x)&=2\cdot1\cdot x^0+3\cdot 2\cdot x+4\cdot3\cdot x^2+\cdots\cr
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)n x^{n-1}.
}
$$
So $$xf''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)n x^n.$$

But, for $|x|<1$,
$$
f(x)={x\over 1-x}
$$ $$f'(x)={d\over dx}{x\over 1-x}={1\over (1-x)^2}$$
$$f''(x)={2\over( 1-x)^3}$$

So $$  {2x\over( 1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)n x^n,$$
for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it